# jdom removes duplicate namespace declaration (xmloutputter)

Tags: java, xml, jdom

jdom seems to remove duplicate namespace declarations. This is a problem when a XML document is embedded into another XML structure, such as for example in the OAI-PHM (open archive initiative). This can be a problem when the surrounding xml is only a container and the embedded document gets extracted later.

Here is some code. The embedded xml is contained in the string with the same name. It declares the xsi namespace. We construct a jdom container, also declaring the xsi namespace. We parse and embed the string. When we print the whole thing the inner xsi namepsace is gone.

```
public static final Namespace OAI_PMH= Namespace.getNamespace(          "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/");
public static final Namespace XSI    = Namespace.getNamespace("xsi",    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
public static final String SCHEMA_LOCATION = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd";
public static final String ROOT_NAME       = "OAI-PMH";


String embeddedxml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <myxml xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"  xsi:schemaLocation=\""
+ "http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
+ " http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/metadata/published/xsd/schema/gmd/gmd.xsd" 
+ " http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx"
+ " http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/metadata/published/xsd/schema/gmx/gmx.xsd\">\"" 
+ "</myxml>";

// loadstring omitted (parse embeddedxml into jdom)
Element xml = loadString(embeddedxml ,false);

Element root = new Element(ROOT_NAME, OAI_PMH);
root.setAttribute("schemaLocation", SCHEMA_LOCATION, XSI);

// insert embedded xml into container structure
root.addContent(xml);


XMLOutputter out = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());


// will see that the xsi namespace declaration from embeddedxml is gone
out.output(root,System.out);
```

I think that XMLoutputter is responsible for this behaviour. Any hints how I can make it preserve the duplicate namepspace?

thanks

Kurt

Comment: Why would it be a problem? If the namespace is actually used in the embedded XML, the mapping will be "restored" when the embedded XML is extracted.

Comment: Indeed. Any XML API will manage the namespace declarations for you when an element is moved to a new document. JDOM is quite correct in removing duplicate definitions.

Comment: the problem seems to be the extraction. AFAIK the way most OAI harvesters behave is that they just "cut" out the embedded xml at string level, this is, the xml is not parsed. It has thus no knowledge of the XML structure and namespaces. In my example you see that there will be a xsi:schemaLocation=.. without the xsi being defined if you cut out the embedded xml out of the container structure.

Comment: You cannot cut and paste XML like that. Eventually, it will fail. 

But, just for the sake of it, use another prefix in the "container".

Comment: problem is that I have no control over what goes into the container. It is used for metadata exchange and the metadata can be anything, and cannot be changed either. I guess it can just not be made part of the DOM if I want it ot be separate.

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing in your code: The declaration of `final static String ROOT_NAME` is not shown and `Element xml` ist not used after initialization.

*If* `ROOT_NAME` is initialized with `"myxml"` somewhere else, then the solution to your problem is, that you just don't add the `xml` element to your document, and the result looks *as if*  you did so.

Comment: I forgot an important part of the code where the embedded xml (xml) is added to the container (root). It is now there